# Delete mysql table data (Bash Script)

Tags: mysql, bash

I was wondering how to delete the values in a MySQL database table from bash.

I have a database called "database" and a table in that database called "table".

Now I want to dump and clear the database from a bash script.

How can I delete the values?

I am using:

```
mysqldump database > $DB_BACKUP/01/table-`date +%Y-%m-%d` (to dump)
```

and now trying to

```
DELETE FROM database.table WHERE filed < CURDATE()-5
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mysql -Bse 'DELETE FROM database.table WHERE filed < CURDATE()- 5'
```

or

```
mysql -Bse 'DELETE FROM table WHERE filed < CURDATE()- 5' database
```

```
mysql --help
```

**-B, --batch**         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      starts with this option ENABLED by default! Disable with

**-s, --silent**        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      Buffer for TCP/IP and socket communication

**-e, --execute=name**  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file)

Comment: Could i know what is -Bse Please

Comment: i've added that to my response